# How to edit deep link parameter in Firebase Dynamic link

Tags: firebase, hyperlink, short, firebase-dynamic-links, deeplink

Is there a REST API to update the Deep link property of Firebase DynamicLink?

The [Google guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/dynamic-links/link-shortener) only shows the process to create a short link
, but there is no mention of how to update the deeplink once created.

**Edit** from Cyril DD :

Using the Firebase website, it's possible to update a dynamic Link and when looking at the network tabs in the console, it calls an API `https://firebasedurablelinks-pa.clients6.google.com/v1/updateDurableLink` where it's possible to completely update the properties of an existing dynamic link.

But then I'm left with two problems:

- I can't see to figure out a way to make this request work in Postman
- I need to update a link that was generated with the `https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/shortLinks` API, and therefore does not appear in the list of links in the firebase console

Comment: did you have any luck?

Comment: You could modify the links using the native solutions for different versions (android, iOS, web...)

Comment: @Juanje can you provide more details on this ? I have generated a short link via the REST API, I've tried using something like `PATCH https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/{{url_encoded_dynamic_link_url}}` but Google doesn't seem to have APIs to patch a link. What do you mean by "modify the links using the native solutions" ? I'm interested / that could be the solution I am looking for

Comment: I'm having problem ingesting dynamic link analytic with its historical data. anyone have luck on this?

Answer (score 1):

This is an intended behavior, but is a known feature request. Short Dynamic Links created programmatically are designed to be shared peer to peer and isn't meant to be modified later on.

The only way to edit short Dynamic Links is through the Firebase console since short links created through the console are likely to be used in campaigns.

If you have more inputs regarding this function, you can file it as a feature request here https://firebase.google.com/support